# Terraform:MacOS:zsh: exec format error: terraform

Tags: macos, terraform, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I first installed `brew install terraform` and it worked fine
But later I tried to install a specific version as below

```
wget -P terraform_bin/ https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.0/terraform_0.12.0_linux_amd64.zip
unzip -o terraform_bin/terraform_0.12.0_linux_amd64.zip -d terraform_bin/
mv terraform_bin/terraform /usr/local/bin
rm -rf terraform_bin
terraform version
```

But now it got messed up with installation in MacOS ,When tried running version its failing

[image]

Comment: *terraform_bin/terraform_0.12.0_**linux_amd64**.zip*. Does that say anything about Mac OS? Mac OS is not Linux, and they're not compatible.

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to use a Linux binary on a Mac, meaning you downloaded the wrong file.

If you look at your wget

```
wget -P terraform_bin/ https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.0/terraform_0.12.0_linux_amd64.zip
```

you will notice that you fetched the Linux version even though you are running on a Mac.

If you go to https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.0 you will see all the files that are available for that version. The one you want is called `terraform_0.12.0_darwin_amd64.zip`. Bear in mind that this particular file is for the Intel architecture, and it will run on current Apple Silicon Macs, but Hashicorp will likely offer an Apple Silicon or Universal version in which case you will want that.

Comment: Just figured out , thanks

Comment: you didn't post your solution ?

Comment: @MugeeshHusain I agree with you, I should have added more details. I edited my response since I've noticed some activity on it lately.